# Checking Ante merīdiem and post merīdiem

Tags: java-8, java, localtime

I have used to LocalTime provided by Java 8 for formatting the time from 1-24 format to 1-12 format in the following code.

```
String  localTime = LocalTime.parse("08:59:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a"));
```

And now with the following code, I have got 1-12 hours format

```
LocalTime localTime1 = LocalTime.parse(localTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a"));
```

My question is "is there any API methods provided by LocalTime" to get ante or post from the given time. Or how to get with clean APIs, instead of manipulating the strings with slice and cut.

Comment: A LocalTime object is an object that holds a value that represents a certain time, that value has nothing to do with AM/PM or any other time format. The format only comes to play when you want to output the time or for any other reason handle it as a string so your question has very little bearing. And please use AM and PM as this has a much clearer meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the elegance of this, but if you want to get a boolean representing whether it is AM or PM, you could do:

```java
boolean isPM = localTime.getHour() >= 12;
```

This variable `isPM` will be `false` if the time is AM and `true` for PM.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any API methods provided by LocalTime

The method is `get`. We need to use it in conjunction with the `ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY` enum constant. It encodes ante meridiem into 0 and post meridiem into 1.

```
    int amPmOf1159 = LocalTime.of(11, 59).get(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY);
    System.out.println(amPmOf1159);
    int amPmOf1200 = LocalTime.of(12, 0).get(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY);
    System.out.println(amPmOf1200);
```

Output is:

> ```
> 0
> 1
> ```